# What happens to your soul if you sell it and then become a vampire or werewolf?

Tags: supernatural

What happens to your soul in *Supernatural* if you sell it and then become a vampire or werewolf?

example:

Dean sells his soul so within the next month he will die and go to hell, but meanwhile he become a vampire? Will the hellhounds still come after him? If he does die while he's a vampire does he's soul go to hell or to purgatory?

This is something that has been bothering me..

And about spoilers! Please dont I'm only at season 7

Comment: I can't give a proper answer. But I can say that this is probably a loop hole in the demon's contract and they will void the demon's contract. But the guy must be willing to become a monster. So I am not sure it would be a **winning** solution. _It would be weirder in regular Vampire lore, since they are soulless beings._

Answer (score 3):

There's no clear answer to this in the show's lore, especially since we don't really get to see a lot of interactions with souls save for the handful of instances on screen.

One thing we do find out in Season 8 is that Purgatory does NOT like having **human** souls in it and will try and purge them.  By that we can kind of assume that vampires, leviathans, and other monsters that end up in Purgatory don't have **human** souls.

However, we are unsure if this transformation "taints" the soul and removes it from any previous negotiations made with demons.  We also haven't seen a Cross Road Demon make a bargain over a monster's soul, maybe because they aren't worth anything or aren't worth as much as human souls.

Comment: I agree with this answer, however, considering the reality-altering powers a Crossroads Demon can invoke upon completing "the sale" (and the seriousness with which MOST of them treat these deals) I think it's safe to say that the Crossroads Demon would take care to make sure the "new reality" they impose does not allow for the opportunity for something that might taint the soul in question to occur.  If you can spontaneously ensure this person will become rich & famous, you can make sure no vampires will cross his path in the next ten years, too.

Comment: @Steve-O I think you're giving the Crosswoards Demons way more power in your comment than they really have.  They have a vested interest to ensure that their deals go through and the ability to manipulate things to a certain extent, but they are still quite limited in what they are able to do.  But again this is all hard to say because nothing like this has happened in the show.